# Jmeter - Java Request Custom Sampler with Spring Boot java client - throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmeter, noclassdeffounderror

Written Java Custom Sampler of JMeter, which will accept a string from the JMeter tool. I need to pass this to a Spring Boot Application which is a simple Java client program. Once I packaged the jars, and I placed it in /lib/ext folder of JMeter, during startup I am getting the below issue. Any one please help on this.

```
2022-04-18 22:56:39,865 DEBUG o.a.j.r.ClassFinder: BOOT-INF/classes/com/**/**/JmsSamplerClient (wrong name: com/**/**/JmsSamplerClient)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/com/**/**/JmsSamplerClient (wrong name: com/**/**/JmsSamplerClient)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$ExtendsClassFilter.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:100) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$ExtendsClassFilter.accept(ClassFinder.java:86) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.3]
```

Comment: Does JMeter really have a `lib/ext` folder? and who or what is looking for `BOOT-INF/classes/com/epam/cerner/JmsSamplerClient`? and why? It should be looking for `com/epam/cerner/JmsSamplerClient`.

Comment: hi.. in your comments, could you please remove the following "com/epam/cerner".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs.

I have resolved this issue by changing the client program to simple non spring boot application. After then, I placed the client program Jar into JMeter lib/ext directory and the dependent spring libraries to lib directory of JMeter. It worked now.

Answer (score -1):

The error says that JMeter cannot find `BOOT-INF/classes/com/**/**/JmsSamplerClient` class in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so make sure to copy it there and restart JMeter to pick up the change.

Going forward be informed that:

- `lib/ext` folder is for JMeter components and [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
- `lib` folder is for dependencies

so split your "jars" accordingly or put everything into an [uber jar](https://imagej.net/develop/uber-jars)

Also given the nature of your custom sampler is that simple you could substitute it with [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) getting the same performance and removing overhead of compiling and copying custom sampler.

Comment: No it doesn't. It says 'wrong name', which implies that it *did* find something at that path.